# How to adjust baking time if I adjust the quantities in the recipe?

Tags: baking, bread, recipe-scaling

[This](https://youtu.be/1r6jV-MaQuc) video gives the following bread recipe:

```
1 kg flour
600 ml water
15 g yeast
18 g salt
```

After doing all the preliminary stuff you'd expect, you shape the dough into a ball and bake it in a Dutch oven at 250 C / 480 F for 30 mins, then lower the heat to 230 C / 430 F for another 30 mins.

The bread it produces is delicious, but that's a huge loaf of bread! Which leads to this question: **if I halve all the quantities, do I also halve the baking time?**

Comment: Although you're only cooking half the volume, the depth to the deepest part would be (1/2)^(1/3) (cube root of 1/2), or 0.7937.  That's a better approximation than 1/2 (and close to Stephie's estimate of 0.75 of the original time), but there are other factors at play, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would not half the baking time, but it might take slightly less time.  The best way to determine if it is done will be to measure the internal temperature.  Most bread is done when the internal temperature hits 190F (88C).

Comment: Off the cuff, I'd say around 45 minutes for the 800g loaf instead of the hour, but that is just based on experience and I always check each individual loaf.